# Add Annotation to 3D Scatterplot in Plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I'm new to this arena and was hoping to get some help.  I'm just starting to work with Plotly and am using it to build a very basic 3D Scatterplot that models some shelves and what items are where.  While I built the "shelf" and the plot renders, I would like to add an Annotation to the text indicating which set of shelves I'm looking at.
[Here is the current output of my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udEAW.jpg) and 
[this is what I am trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MC6xo.jpg)

I've tried reviewing the documentation and attempted to add an annotation (as I have for 2D Analogs) and while the code compiles, the text does not show up.

```
p <- plot_ly(all, x = X, y = Y, z = Z,  
    text = paste0("Candy: ", SKU,"; QTY: ", Qty), 
    color = OccupiedPct, 
    colors = cols,
    hoverinfo = "text",
    type = "scatter3d", mode = "markers") %>%
layout(
   title = "Shelves"
)
sub <- list(
    x = 3,
    y = 2,
    z = 0,
    text = "Shelf1",
    xref = "x",
    yref = "y",
    zref = "z",
    showarrow = FALSE
)
p %>%
   layout(annotations = sub)
```

Thank you in advance!  Mike

#

**UPDATE**
Thank you @MLavoie for your answer and sorry for excluding a reproducible dataset.  Unfortunately I could not replicate what you had done.  I noticed that the z-axis on your plot was set to zero and I tried to reset mine without success.  However, even adjusting the point to be in the plot range, I still couldn't get it to show up.  Here is the plot I got:
[image: Output]
when I ran this code

```
set.seed(100)
d <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]

p <- plot_ly(d, x = carat, y = price, z=depth, text = paste("Clarity: ",     clarity),
         type="scatter3d", mode="markers")

p %>% 
  add_trace(x = 2.5, y = 5000, z = 56, type = "scatter3d", text = "test", mode = "text") %>% 
  add_trace(x = 2.5, y = 15000, z = 56, type = "scatter3d", text = "test", mode = "text") %>% 
  layout(
    xaxis = list(range = c(0, 5)),
    yaxis = list(range(0,20000)),
    zaxis = list(range(0,100)),
    showlegend = FALSE)
```

In the interest of completeness, here is my Session Info:

```
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] plotly_2.0.16 ggplot2_2.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.3      digest_0.6.9     grid_3.2.1       plyr_1.8.3       R6_2.1.2         jsonlite_0.9.19  gtable_0.1.2     magrittr_1.5     scales_0.3.0     httr_1.1.0      
[11] viridis_0.3.2    tools_3.2.1      htmlwidgets_0.5  munsell_0.4.2    yaml_2.1.13      base64enc_0.1-3  colorspace_1.2-6 htmltools_0.3    gridExtra_2.0.0
```

Thanks again!

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: I'm so sorry I didn't provide that!  I see you already answered the question so I am going to test that out though it looks like the answer.  Thank you again @Mlavoie and sorry for the incompleteness of my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the iris dataset (you did not provide a reproducible example) you could try:

```
set.seed(100)
d <- diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]

p <- plot_ly(d, x = carat, y = price, z=depth, text = paste("Clarity: ", clarity),
        type="scatter3d", mode="markers")

p %>% 
add_trace(x = 2.5, y = 5000, z = 0, type = "scatter3d", text = "test", mode = "text") %>% 
add_trace(x = 2.5, y = 15000, z = 0, type = "scatter3d", text = "test", mode = "text") %>% 
layout(showlegend = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @MLavoie, I couldn't get this to work and included my attempt in the original post if you wouldn't mind taking another look.  Thank you!

Comment: when I run your code, I don't have any problem, but I have a different plotly version (plotly_3.4.13). try to upgrade yours and rerun the code.

Comment: That did it!  Thank you so much!!!  I had to upgrade plotly and ggplot2 but now it works.

Comment: Sorry! I thought I had, but just did now! Thanks and have a great weekend!