# How to make 3D annotations in Julia Plots

Tags: annotations, julia, plots.jl

The annotation attribute in [Julia Plots](https://github.com/tbreloff/Plots.jl) seems to only take tuples of x,y coordinates and a label according to the [documentation](https://juliaplots.github.io/attributes/).  Is there any way to do this on a 3D plot?  For example:

```
tvec=0:0.1:4*pi
plot(sin, tvec)
annotate!(pi/2,1.0,"max")
annotate!(3*pi/2,-1.0,"min")
```

produces
[image]
but how do you add something to

```
tvec=0:0.1:4*pi
plot(tvec, sin(tvec), cos(tvec))
```

Using the same type of `annotate!` command seems to annotate onto a superimposed 2D coordinate.
[image]

Comment: What you are using as the Plots.jl back-end?

Comment: It looks like plotlyjs from the aesthetics

Comment: @FelipeLema is correct.  I used plotly which I like as it lets me rotate the view of the 3D image.  The annotate phenomena I mentioned occurs there, but not in pyplot as pyplot only annotates the 2D.  I can edit and add images if helpful (I'm new to this stuff so always appreciate learning how to make questions/comments better).

Comment: apparently, this is not supported in plots.jl, but it is supported in [plotlyjs using R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37596865/add-annotation-to-3d-scatterplot-in-plotly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it's not available yet https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl/issues/362

Answer (score 1):

According to the Julia Plots ([Plots.jl](http://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/)) docs found [here](http://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/backends/#For-the-impatient), GR, PyPlot, and Plotly(JS) all support 3D plots in some form. It is worth diving into some examples [here](http://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/generated/gr/) to explore how these different backends support 3D plots.